# Raster doesn't create right output file (.gri and .grd file) instead of an .tif file

Tags: r, tiff, r-raster

I'm using Rstudio on a Mac. I use the Dismo and Raster packages to set the levels of the resolution, extent and crs all equal for different files.

The whole script works however but the output should be a .tif file however RStudio exports the output as a .gri and .grd file.

Did I miss installing an extra package to have the right output or has it something to do with using a Mac version of RStudio because the original script was written on a Windows version?

Code:

````
> library(raster)
> #Put all your raster files in the working directory, including BedCrop provided
> # load in your raster environmental files
> RastList<-list.files(getwd(), pattern = ".tif")
> r <- lapply(RastList, raster)
> r # The extents, crs, resolution might be different for each raster
[[1]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 4320, 8640, 37324800  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.04166667, 0.04166667  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : Annual precipitation_wc2.1_2.5m_bio_12.tif 
names      : Annual.precipitation_wc2.1_2.5m_bio_12 
values     : 0, 11246  (min, max)


[[2]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2395, 3379, 8092705  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0306, 0.018  (x, y)
extent     : -41.28155, 62.11585, 31.29335, 74.40335  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : BedCrop.tif 
names      : BedCrop 
values     : 0, 8200  (min, max)


[[3]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 4320, 8640, 37324800  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.04166667, 0.04166667  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : Elevation_wc2.1_2.5m_elev.tif 
names      : Elevation_wc2.1_2.5m_elev 
values     : -415, 7412  (min, max)


[[4]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 4320, 8640, 37324800  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.04166667, 0.04166667  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : Temp_JAN_wc2.1_2.5m_tavg_01.tif 
names      : Temp_JAN_wc2.1_2.5m_tavg_01 
values     : -46.096, 34.1  (min, max)


> # Choose a raster with the resolution, extent you want and crs=wgs84, use it as a template
> template <- r[[2]] #I choose you BedCrop!
> #Reproject and mask each raster to the same CRS and extent as your template
> r[[1]] <- projectRaster(r[[1]], template) #repeat for each layer of the raster stack (r[[3]], r[[4]]...)
Warning message:
In projectRaster(r[[1]], template) : input and ouput crs are the same
> r[[1]]<-mask(r[[1]], template)
> r[[3]] <- projectRaster(r[[3]], template)
Warning message:
In projectRaster(r[[3]], template) : input and ouput crs are the same
> r[[3]]<-mask(r[[3]], template)
> r[[4]] <- projectRaster(r[[4]], template)
Warning message:
In projectRaster(r[[4]], template) : input and ouput crs are the same
> r[[4]]<-mask(r[[4]], template)
> r #check they have the same extent, resolution, crs
[[1]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2395, 3379, 8092705  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0306, 0.018  (x, y)
extent     : -41.28155, 62.11585, 31.29335, 74.40335  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : Annual.precipitation_wc2.1_2.5m_bio_12 
values     : 107.9981, 2992.399  (min, max)


[[2]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2395, 3379, 8092705  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0306, 0.018  (x, y)
extent     : -41.28155, 62.11585, 31.29335, 74.40335  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : BedCrop.tif 
names      : BedCrop 
values     : 0, 8200  (min, max)


[[3]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2395, 3379, 8092705  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0306, 0.018  (x, y)
extent     : -41.28155, 62.11585, 31.29335, 74.40335  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : Elevation_wc2.1_2.5m_elev 
values     : -5.991715, 3844.619  (min, max)


[[4]]
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2395, 3379, 8092705  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0306, 0.018  (x, y)
extent     : -41.28155, 62.11585, 31.29335, 74.40335  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : Temp_JAN_wc2.1_2.5m_tavg_01 
values     : -16.45166, 16.23138  (min, max)


>   # 1: "Name file" + "Reprojected"
> writeRaster(r[[1]], "Annual precipitation_Reprojected_wc2.1_2.5m_bio_12 ", type="tif") #repeat for each layer, with correct name ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writeRaster` does not have a `type =` argument.  The correct argument to use is `format = 'GTiff'`.  Alternatively, just specify the type in the file name:

```
writeRaster(r[[1]], "Annual precipitation_Reprojected_wc2.1_2.5m_bio_12.tif")
```

Comment: Thanks, the new code worked as it should!